# Windows command prompt won't show results of commands like "java -version"

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Having a problem with the Windows 10 cmd. When I write "java -version" or "gradle -v" or other commands, it pops up an "**Allow this app to make changes to your device?**" from "**Java SE Runtime Environment**". When I allow it prints nothing to the console.

Been a while since I used this PC, so probably I have changed something that shouldn't be changed, but no clue what it is. It runs like it should when I open cmd as administrator, but this wasn't neccessary before, so I hoped that I could make it like it was before.

Comment: Are you running cmd as an administrator? Right click on cmd and select run as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Find your java.exe
2. Open its properties, go to compatibility tab
3. Uncheck "run this program as administrator" option.